# Pandas - access previous time data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column based off of two columns when a previous condition was met. On the table below if the buyer == True then the new column profit will show 2 for row two and 4 for row three. When running the code on column three I need to access the qty and price of column one due to it being the first False command on a previous date.

| time(index) | price | qty | buyer | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-06 | 2 | 4 | False | -8 |
| 2021-11-07 | 3 | 2 | True | 2 |
| 2021-11-08 | 4 | 2 | True | 4 |
| 2021-11-09 | 5 | 4 | False | -20 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using np.where

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
time,price,qty,buyer
2021-11-06,2,4,False
2021-11-07,3,2,True
2021-11-08,4,2,True
2021-11-09,5,4,False
""")).set_index('time')

df['profit'] = df['price']*df['qty']*np.where(df['buyer'],1,-1)

df
```

The idea is that we multiple the price by the quantity for every row, and multipy by 1 if the buyer is True, or -1 if the buyer is False